# Access a JSON value inside a JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a dropdown and there is an `onchange()` function and it calls an `ajax` request, which points to a function in the controller.

I want to print all the values like  `client_address` which will print "Turin" like that. I want that in javascript.

```
"billing_details":
{"{contact_firstname}":"Luis",
"{contact_lastname}":"Garcia",
"{contact_email}":"lg@gmail.com",
"{client_company}":null,
"{client_phonenumber}":"1234566",
"{client_country}":"French Southern Territories",
"{client_city}":"Venis",
"{client_zip}":"13212",
"{client_state}":"Djbouti",
"{client_address}":"Turin",
"{password}":"",
"{client_building_no}":"12",
"{client_country_id}":"79",
"{client_calling_code}":"262",
"{client_id}":"25",
"{country_short}":"TF"}}
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON format. Maybe you wanted to write `console.log(obj.billing_details.client_address)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the values by obj['key']

```js
var data={"billing_details":{
"{contact_firstname}":"Luis",
"{contact_lastname}":"Garcia",
"{contact_email}":"lg@gmail.com",
"{client_company}":null,
"{client_phonenumber}":"1234566",
"{client_country}":"French Southern Territories",
"{client_city}":"Venis",
"{client_zip}":"13212",
"{client_state}":"Djbouti",
"{client_address}":"Turin",
"{password}":"",
"{client_building_no}":"12",
"{client_country_id}":"79",
"{client_calling_code}":"262",
"{client_id}":"25",
"{country_short}":"TF"}}
console.log(data.billing_details['{client_address}'])
```